# Google Developers Console でエラーカウント表示

Tags: gcm

下記URLでエラーカウントが表示されます。
https://console.developers.google.com/project
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このエラーは何を意味しているのですか？
APIはGCMで公開APIのブラウザキーをサーバーに設定しているだけです。

よろしくお願い致します。